# Change the size of drop downs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, dropdown

I have created 2 dropdowns  but I am unable to change their size..I want the dropdown of screen width 
here is my  code

```
 <select id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedArea">
  <option ng-repeat="(key,prop) in result" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
<select id="repeatSelect1" ng-model="selectedState">
  <option ng-repeat="state in result[selectedArea]" value="state">{{state}}</option>
</select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nNsM4VMVeHXS2hDIsAAd?p=preview

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of each  to 100%. Use the below code

```html
 <select id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedArea" style="width:100%">
  <option ng-repeat="(key,prop) in result" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
<select id="repeatSelect1" ng-model="selectedState" style="width:100%">
  <option ng-repeat="state in result[selectedArea]" value="state">{{state}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add style witdh 100% to your select

like this

```
<select style="width:100%" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedArea">
```

Answer (score 0):

To change size of the dropdown list you can write following statement in js

```
jQuery('#repeatSelect').css('width','100%');
```

'#repeatSelect' - It's the id of dropdown(select)control.Above statement should be exist on document ready.